# what is difference b/w run python code in pycharm and terminal?

Tags: python, pycharm

when i run below python code  in pycharm

```
import pokitdok
print dir(pokitdok)
```

i got below output

```
['__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', 
 '__name__', '__package__', 'pokitdok']
```

but when i run in terminal

```
import pokitdok
print dir(pokitdok)
```

i get below output

```
['__author__', '__builtins__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', 
 '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__title__', 
 '__version__', 'absolute_import', 'api', 'pokitdok']
```

Comment: Pycharm installs its own interpreter, so you may have different versions of python and this module in the pycharm interpreter and your system installed interpreter. Check the reported version when you start python; you can also configure pycharm to use the system interpreter. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code ran in different environments, in Pycharm you can set separate environment by [virtualenv](https://launchpad.net/virtualenv) for running your project